# How can I block moving up/down with multiple j,k keystrokes?

Tags: vim

I learned moving with `hjkl` by blocking arrow keys.

I'd like to do something similiar for moving up/down with `jjjjjj`/`kkkkk`. 
For example whenever I press `j` 4 times in a row with small delays it would jump back to original position, so I'd have to think how to move smarter to the place I want.

Comment: you may have mappings with `jj` or `jjj`?

Comment: Not a technical problem at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a fan of technical solutions to this problem (I'd rather critically reflect on my own typing occasionally), but this can be done by storing subsequent keypresses in an array, and complaining if the size becomes too large:

```
let g:pos = []
let g:keys = []
function! RecordKey( key )
    if v:count || get(g:keys, 0, '') != a:key
        " Used [count], or different key; start over.
        let g:keys = [a:key]
        let g:pos = getpos('.')
        echo
        return 1
    endif

    call add(g:keys, a:key)
    if len(g:keys) > 4
        " Too many identical movements (without count).
        let g:keys = [a:key]
        call setpos('.', g:pos)

        echohl ErrorMsg
        echomsg 'Try again'
        echohl None

        return 0
    endif

    echo
    return 1
endfunction

" Reset counter after a delay in movement.
autocmd CursorHold * let g:keys = []

nnoremap <silent> j :<C-u>if RecordKey('j')<Bar>execute 'normal!' (v:count ? v:count : '') . 'j'<Bar>endif<CR>
nnoremap <silent> k :<C-u>if RecordKey('k')<Bar>execute 'normal!' (v:count ? v:count : '') . 'k'<Bar>endif<CR>
" Add more movements as you wish.
```

(Trying this out, I'm already annoyed by this :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following mappings:

```
nnoremap jjjj j
nnoremap kkkk k
```

This will make fast movement up and down very cumbersome. Unfortunately it will also prohibit a normal 'j' from executing very fast, as Vim will wait to see whether you want to add anything else after the first keypress to complete the binding. This can be circumvented by pressing another key afterwards (e.g. switching to insert mode with i/I/a/A or the like).

Comment: I tried it and using single `j` is too slow for me :/

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa Why are you using the single `j`? With the next key you type the `j` is executed by Vim. All you would need for this simple solution is to visualize where the cursor is going to end up.